# How to control array sorting in knockout.mapping?

Tags: javascript, sorting, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Please find the [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/iluzyanin/9MkGy/19/). I have an observable array of persons, each person has id, firstName and lastName. User sorts this array by any property, in both directions.
Then, at some point, I need to update my array, which I do using knockout.mapping.fromJS function:

```
this.rockStarsMapping = {
    create: function (options) {
        // just to make sure that key works
        console.log('created');
        return options.data;
    },
    key: function(data) {
        return data.id;
    }
};
this.rockStars = ko.observableArray([]);
this.getRockStars = function() {
    // here should be some ajax call instead of a stub
    var newRockStars = [
        { id: 1, firstName: "John", lastName: "Lehnon" },
        { id: 2, firstName: "Paul", lastName: "McCartney" },
        ...
    ];
    ko.mapping.fromJS(newRockStars, self.rockStarsMapping, self.rockStars);
};
```

The problem is, that new array is sorted by id (for example), and this sorting prevails over sorting in existing array.
My current solution is to remember current sort column name and sort direction, but it doesn't work right, because other columns may have other sort directions. For example, in my jsfiddle code, try to sort by Id descending first (6, 5, 4, ...), then sort by First name. Now if you click "Get rock stars", the sorting order in Id column changes, which is not a desired behavior.
How to keep sorting order as is? And what more important - how to make sure new items would be in the right place of an array?

Comment: Why don't you use the .sort() function, which you can use with a custom sorting, fitted to your needs?
See: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html

Comment: Actually, I do use sort in my current solution - in sortStars function (see jsfiddle). The problem is, I don't know how to make mapping plugin to remember the history of sorting on all previous columns (is this possible at all?). Anyways, I've got another solution - when sorting function meets 2 equal values, than it should sort, e.g. ascending, using some unique field ("id" in my example). The "sorting history" is lost this way, but this is the best I've come up with.